# Type Mismatch when combining two csv files in VB

Tags: sql, vba, csv, datasource

I had my code working just fine, but when I generated new updated versions of the CSV files it suddenly errors out on me and gives me a type mismatch catch.

Here is the code that I have right now.

```
 Dim A As String = "ADusers.csv"
    Dim B As String = "MlnExp.csv"
    Dim filePath As String = "C:\CSV"

    Try
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & (filePath) & "\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes'"

        Dim sSql As String = "SELECT *" _
        & "FROM ([" & (B) & "] B LEFT JOIN [" & (A) & "] A ON B.EmployeeNumber = A.employeeID)"

        Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim Command As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSql, conn)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        conn.Open()

        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sSql, conn)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGrid1.DataSource = dt
        DataGrid1.Update()

        conn.Close()
        lblStatus.Text = "CSV combined... Now saving to file."


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)


    End Try
```

Before it would go through, combine the two CSV files, and then display them in my datagrid. But now my catch is throwing back

> Type mismatch in expression

Comment: have you tried debugging it at all?

Comment: Yes. The error I get  
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Type mismatch in expression.`

Answer (score 0):

i would check B.EmployeeNumber = A.employeeID
in both of your file one is a text value (left align) and the other is a a interger(right align)

Comment: Well they both looked like they were right aligned in the CSV file, but when I actually clicked the align button it magically decided to work... I have both csv files being written by PowerShell so they should be equal. Any idea how I can force them to stay that way?

Comment: What about within VB? Can I force them to be interger?

Comment: in your sql statement maybe tis would work ......SELECT *" _& "FROM ([" & (B) & "] B LEFT JOIN [" & (A) & "] A ONCAST(B.EmployeeNumber AS INT) = CAST(A.employeeID AS INT)

Comment: Now I'm getting an error message  
`IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)`

Comment: I figured something out. When I export the MlnExport file from PowerShell I had a `-NoTypeInformation` in there which I am guessing deleted the integer property. Now the only problem is that it puts a line at the top that says `#TYPE System.Data.DataRow`  I guess I just need to figure out how to get rid of that without screwing up the data types